# Making a table and a histogram from various counters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, histogram

Here I have a code that initiates by a list, it takes two random letter and put them back into the main list. Then I count each letter from each generated list:

```
import random
import collections


def randMerge(l:list, count:int) -> list:
    return l + [random.sample(l,k=count)]

def flatten(d):
    return [i for b in [[c] if not isinstance(c, list) else flatten(c)
 for c in d] for i in b]

num = 2
aList = ['A','B','C','D']
newList = aList[:]
    for _ in range(3):
        newList = randMerge(newList,num)
        print(newList)
        new_counts = collections.Counter(flatten(newList))
        print(new_counts)
```

which gives:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ['A', 'C']]
Counter({'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'D': 1})
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'A']]
Counter({'A': 3, 'C': 2, 'D': 2, 'B': 1})
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'A'], ['A', 'B']]
Counter({'A': 4, 'B': 2, 'C': 2, 'D': 2})
```

Now I wonder how can I make a dataframe such that each column the numbers in counters and the row will be representing the letters. I did this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(new_counts, orient='index')
```

yet this gives me only the last Counter. Also how can I make a histogram of each Counter and show them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need each column to represent the contents of a `Counter` object, you can create your dataframe from the list of objects, then transpose.

```
import collections, random, pandas as pd

def randMerge(l:list, count:int) -> list:
    return l + [random.sample(l,k=count)]

def flatten(d):
    return [i for b in [[c] if not isinstance(c, list) else flatten(c)
            for c in d] for i in b]

num = 2
aList = ['A','B','C','D']

res = []
newList = aList[:]

for _ in range(3):
    newList = randMerge(newList,num)
    new_counts = collections.Counter(flatten(newList))
    res.append(new_counts)

print(res)

# [Counter({'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'D': 1}),
#  Counter({'C': 3, 'A': 2, 'D': 2, 'B': 1}),
#  Counter({'C': 4, 'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'D': 2})]

df = pd.DataFrame(res).T

print(df)

#    0  1  2
# A  2  2  2
# B  1  1  1
# C  2  3  5
# D  1  2  3
```

Comment: Thanks I am trying to do the histogram by this: df.plot(kind='hist')  yet it gives me <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x116eaf518> is there any problem in what I am doing?

Comment: @William, OK that's a separate question. You need to split each problem into components and research them separately. A problem such as "create dataframe in this format, then plot histogram" is too broad for SO. This isn't a code-writing service. We're here to help, provide Q&A, not a solution-providing service.

Comment: @William, as I said - happy to help. You're more than welcome to ask a separate question on histograms, just make sure it hasn't been asked before and that it's clear from the first few lines, not in the final sentence! Thks.